# Apply to nth-childs but not divs

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the nth-child parameter to put background on some elements inside a div. I am using bootstrap and i wanted to also show a tooltip when the user is above an element. Currently my css is like this:

```
.br-widget a.br-active:nth-child(1),
.br-widget a.br-selected:nth-child(1) {
    background: #FB0A01;
}

.br-widget a.br-active:nth-child(2),
.br-widget a.br-selected:nth-child(2) {
    background: #F94E00;
}

.br-widget a.br-active:nth-child(3),
.br-widget a.br-selected:nth-child(3) {
    background: #F96400;
}

.br-widget a.br-active:nth-child(4),
.br-widget a.br-selected:nth-child(4) {
    background: #FA9B01;
}

.br-widget a.br-active:nth-child(5),
.br-widget a.br-selected:nth-child(5) {
    background: #FAB800;
}

.br-widget a.br-active:nth-child(6),
.br-widget a.br-selected:nth-child(6) {
    background: #F9D100;
}

.br-widget a.br-active:nth-child(7),
.br-widget a.br-selected:nth-child(7) {
    background: #EFE601;
}

.br-widget a.br-active:nth-child(8),
.br-widget a.br-selected:nth-child(8) {
    background: #E7E504;
}

.br-widget a.br-active:nth-child(9),
.br-widget a.br-selected:nth-child(9) {
    background: #C3E60C;
}

.br-widget a.br-active:last-child,
.br-widget a.br-selected:last-child {
    background: #47E21A;
}
```

The problem that i am facing is that the tooltip is creating a div AFTER the element that it's creating it, so its breaking up my css since it's becoming a child of the initial div (br-widget).

Is there a way i can discard a child in the css if its a div ? or even if that child has a class of "tooltip" on it. Like something like this:

```
.br-widget a.br-active:nth-child(9):not(div),
.br-widget a.br-selected:nth-child(9):not(div) {
    background: #C3E60C;
}
```

Comment: This question is asked far too frequently. basically it is not possible to filter nth-child like that. You can't do *'nth-child that isn't a div'*

Comment: Assuming that the elements you want to apply the styling on are all the same type, you could use `nth-of-type()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:nth-of-type`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/) instead of `:nth-child`. With `:nth-of-type` you only count element of that type, not every child.

Comment: I dont get it...how can :nth-of-type be used, when its selecting elements only...and doesnt separate classes.

Comment: Just put `:nth-of-type` instead of `:nth-child`

Comment: omg..i've been scratching my head with this for 2h now....lol...i though nth-type was not gonna do it....didnt even try :)   Thanks man